# Scraping AJAX content with Scrapy when page needs POST information first

Tags: json, ajax, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a site with Scrapy anf the site has Ajax content. I can't post a link because it requires a login to view the content. The content displays a loading message for a few seconds and then loads a table.

I am trying to scrape `https://www.example.com/products/my-product.html`. Looking in the Firefox dev tools, I can see there is a POST for `http://www.example.com/warehouse/warehouse/refreshProductQuote/`. If I open that link while in the session I see the JSON data. On the response section, I see the JSON response. It looks like when I go to the product page it does a POST to the other URL, I see it sending the product id in the params section, and I get a json response. I've been looking at examples but they are more basic and don't involve having to send a post first.

Once I get to `https://www.example.com/products/my-product.html`, how to I post the product id to `http://www.example.com/warehouse/warehouse/refreshProductQuote/` to get to the json data? Or am I thinking about this all wrong? I tried using a form request, as I'm new and that's one the the few things I can do, but it's not a form and it errored saying there was no form element.

Comment: if it's not a form request, you can try a python post request. Check the same in postman. that's only I can say from your inputs.

Comment: You can use `scrapy.FormRequest` for this.